# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'. Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

My project is written in dart language under flutter framework and database is Firebase. IDE I am using for my project is Android Studio in Windows.

The project seems to be working on java 11 as per the error but after checking the properties as well as gradle properties and project structure it is clearly visible that it is set to java 17.

I have tried to change the java version but it is still not working for my specific project other project seems to be running which I have created for test purposes.

The error showing after executing the `main.dart` file is shown below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Build file 'D:\flutter project\my_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 30s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your jvm version in build.gradle and your JDK version in the settings:

1. in your build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

2. in your AndroidStudio's gradle settings:
   Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK

Afterwards you might need to clear caches and restart AndroidStudio as well..

Comment: IMHO the second point is the important point.